# Why is the last element of this array being spliced instead of a middle one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, array-splice

For some reason when trying to splice a middle index from the array, enemies, the last element is removed instead. I've asked a couple of people but they have no idea as to what the problem is.

If i shoot a bullet at the 5th enemy the last element of the array is spliced instead of index 5.

```
enemies.forEach(function(element, index){
    for(var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
        if(bullets[i].X + 5 > element.X && bullets[i].X < element.X+30 && 
            bullets[i].Y + 5 > element.Y && bullets[i].Y < element.Y+30){
            //These conditions look messy but they work

            console.log(index); //This Outputs the Correct Index
            enemies.splice(index, 1); //<- Splices The Last Index instead of a specific one

            bullets.splice(i, 1); 
        }
    }
})
```

This Link has a copy of my entire code and an alternate version of this function
https://pastebin.com/Q7swAh1a

1. Why isn't the correct index being spliced?
2. How do I fix this code to make the correct index be spliced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
for(var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
    enemies[i].Draw((66*i)+18, 50, i);//Here is the bug
    enemies[i].Move();
}
```

and here

```
this.Draw = function(x, y, i) {
    this.X = x;//These 2 lines overwrite the real positions
    this.Y = y;

    ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
    ctx.fillRect(this.X, this.Y, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillText(i, this.X, this.Y);
}
```

You draw your enemies based on their index in the array instead of their own position.

This should work:

```
for(var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
    enemies[i].Draw(i);
    enemies[i].Move();
}

this.Draw = function(i) {

    ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
    ctx.fillRect(this.X, this.Y, 30, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillText(i, this.X, this.Y);//i would be the index in the array and changes with splice()
}
```

Comment: The last two lines of this.Draw were for me to check what the index of each enemy in the canvas were. I commented those lines out and used your code but if i shoot at an enemy with for example index 2, the enemy with index 11 is removed instead. How do i fix that?

Comment: The correct enemy gets removed, but in your code the position of the enemies is not based on their real position rather you give them their position in .draw and the values passed are calculated based on the index.

Comment: Oh okay i got it thanks, it seems so simple now that i see it.